# How to create multiple textfield in tableview cell dynamically

Tags: swift4

This is what I tried .....

Can anyone help me understand the below code that creates a textfield ? A summary about the following code would be very useful.

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 10
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
          return 4
    }else if  section == 1 {
        return 3
    }else{
        return 1
    }

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DynamicViewController") as! DynamicTableViewCell


    for var i in (0..<indexPath.count).reversed()
    {

            var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 340, height: 40))
            myTextField.placeholder = "Enter Email Address \(i)"
            myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
            cell.addSubview(myTextField)

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: If this code is hat you tried? can you give a summery what is it doing? what you like to achieve .. and where you are stuck?

Comment: I want different no. of textfield in each cell dynamically